# Can a single Spring Cloud Function associate with multiple input and output channels?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka, spring-cloud-function

I need to associate a function with multiple input and output channels using spring cloud stream 3.0 and I'm using below configuration in application.yml. But for some reason my below function is not receiving messages.

> spring:   cloud:
> function:
> definition: producer1;producer2;numbersWordsFn
> stream:
> bindings:
> producer1-out-0:
> destination: numbers-topic
> producer2-out-0:
> destination: words-topic
> numbersWordsFn-in-0:
> destination: numbers-topic
> numbersWordsFn-in-1:
> destination: words-topic
> numbersWordsFn-out-0:
> destination: ex-topic1
> numbersWordsFn-out-1:
> destination: ex-topic2
> kafka:
> binder:
> brokers: localhost:9092
> auto-create-topics: true

```
@Bean
public Function<Flux<Integer>, Flux<String>> numbersWordsFn() {
    //
}
```

Comment: Could you format your `yaml` configuration above? It is hard to read since it is un-formatted. When you want multple output bindings, you may want to resort to using `Tuple`s from Project Reactor. See this section from the ref docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/reference/spring-cloud-stream/producing-and-consuming-messages.html#functions-with-multiple-input-and-output-arguments